# Is there any difference between mode value 0777 and 777

Tags: permissions

I saw a code change at work, where the mode values were changed from 777 to 0777 to make nfs setattr work. What is the difference in the 2 values?

Comment: [whats the difference between chmod 777 and chmod 7777](https://superuser.com/q/592309/241386)

Comment: Came across the same issue whilst using php built-in FS related functions like `mkdir()`. [0777 vs 777](http://digitalfortress.tech/php/difference-file-mode-0777-vs-777/)

Answer (score 107, accepted):

If you're passing them to `chmod` (the command-line program), there is no difference. But in a C program or similar, `0777` is octal (three sets of three 1 bits, which is what you intend), while `777` is decimal, and it's quite a different bit pattern. (`chmod` will interpret any numeric argument as octal, hence no leading zero is necessary.)

0777 (octal)      == binary `0b 111 111 111`    == permissions `rwxrwxrwx`     (== decimal `511`)

777 (decimal) == binary `0b 1 100 001 001` == permissions `sr----x--x` (== octal `1411`)

Comment: Just to be clear -- the value you pass to the `chmod` command is always interpreted as octal. Using `chmod 888` will give an error.

Comment: but each digit is octal, not the whole number itself.

Comment: A string of octal digits _is_ an octal number. `chmod` interprets a numeric argument as octal, regardless of prefix. (But really the number itself has no function; just the digits, or rather the bits.)

Comment: So, in a C program, if you want to pass `1777`, you need to write `01777`?

Comment: @Faheem, that's right. Octal `1777` is written `01777` in C. (Or you could write `1023`, which is the same number in decimal. But don't :-)

Answer (score 6):

The first bit is used for the sticky bit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit

If you set permission using 4 digits, the first will set or remove this bit.

Comment: The sticky bit is not the first bit but the third one. The first is the suid bit and the second the sgid one. If you set permissions using three digits, the missing first digit will also affect (i.e. remove) these three bits.

Comment: You are right. Ergo, the "answer provided by alexis is wring.

Comment: @jlliagre From the chmod man page - "Omitted digits are assumed to be leading zeros.". Also, the first digit of 4 *is* the sticky bit. From the man page again: "The first digit selects the set user ID (4) and set group ID (2) and restricted deletion or sticky (1) attributes. The second digit selects permissions for the user who owns the file: read (4), write (2), and execute (1); the third selects permissions for other users in the file's group, with the same values; and the fourth for other users not in the file's group, with the same values.".

Comment: @FaheemMitha, omitted digits are assumed to be leading zeros thus **will** remove the aforementioned bits. Also, you seem to confuse bits and digits, I was commenting about the first bit, not the first digit.

Comment: @jlliagre Ok, fair enough.

Comment: The "will... _or remove_ " bit is actually not entirely correct, and at least implementation dependent (see my answer below). On Linux, a `chmod 0750` will _not_ remove existing setuid/setuid bits.

Answer (score 2):

The interesting answer is:

- there is **no difference between `0700` and `700`**, as explained in the other answers
- but **there *is* a difference between `00700` and `0700`** (for directories)

At least that's the case for GNU coreutils' chmod version, which is the default on Linux.

See this example:

```
$ ls -ld mydir
drws--s--- 4 myuser mygroup 4096 Jul  8 09:27 mydir
$ chmod 0710 mydir ; ls -ld mydir                   # surprise ahead -- s-bits remain:
drws--s--- 4 myuser mygroup 4096 Jul  8 09:27 mydir
$ chmod 00710 mydir ; ls -ld mydir                  # _now_ they're gone:
drwx--x--- 4 myuser mygroup 4096 Jul  8 09:27 mydir
```

This is to avoid accidental deletion of setuid/setgid bits for directories. For details, see the [chmod](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Directory-Setuid-and-Setgid.html) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux system there are two types permissions are available:

1. File Permission
2. Special Permission

In File permission we set permission on files and folders:

The permissions are:

- read(4)
- write(2)
- execute(1)

While in special permission three types of permission are:

- SUID(4)
- SGID(2)
- Sticky Bit(1)

In your question you ask what is difference, so there is no any difference between `chmod 777 and 0777` because there is `no any octal value` which show value of (0) zero.